# WSGI test sample not working in apache2.2.22

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to run a test wsgi application in apache 2.2.22 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. There are two other php websites hosted in the same apache.

I have the below app.wsgi in /var/www/wsgi folder.

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

However, when I open the link in the browser it opens the directory in the browser.
When I tried opening the app.wsgi, it shows the source file as is. It fails to execute the code through WSGI.

I have installed libapache2-mod-wsgi. Below is the apache settings for this virtualhost - wsgi.conf at /etc/apache2/sites-available.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName xyz
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/wsgi>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI

        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
       allow from all
   </Directory>

   WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi /var/www/wsgi/app.wsgi
   LogLevel info
   ErrorLog "/var/www/wsgi/error.log"
   CustomLog "/var/www/wsgi/access.log" combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Please help me troubleshoot this. I have performed a2dissite default. I have performed a2ensite for other websites hosted, which are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you try "opening the app.wsgi"? Your WSGIScriptAlias is set to `\wsgi`, so that is the address you should go to.

Comment: In the browser, I tried http://address/wsgi, it gives the directory, while http://address/wsgi/app.wsgi comes with the source code..What is causing this?

Comment: I don't know, but you should not have that DocumentRoot or that whole Directory section: they might be interfering, you should remove them.

Comment: I removed DocumentRoot /var/www/wsgi from the virtual host settings. But still no luck.